# Hudson - Send Status Change emails only

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson, hudson-plugins

I am running few scheduled jobs periodically every 5 minutes. How to send status change emails only and no duplicate emails. Please advise.
When job is moved from

```
Failure to Success -- Send an email --> "Fixed" trigger working well in this scenario.
Success to Failure - Send an email --> don't see any appropriate trigger.
```

I am looking at Editable Notifications plug-in. [image]

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins, the [Email Ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) has a [trigger](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/trigger/FirstFailureTrigger.java) called "First Failure" which does exactly what you want.

You appear to be using the old [email-ext](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin) which doesn't have [that option](https://github.com/hudson3-plugins/email-ext-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/trigger). So you can't restrict emails the way you want using that plugin.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately our company is using Hudson. So I need to check compatibility of new plugin with Hudson and overwrite the old version. I need to explore the way to install Jenkins plug-ins manually.

Comment: There's a good chance it isn't compatible (and that there isn't a ported plugin.) I'm mentioning the Jenkins one because you are likely to find that when you search.